# YouTube Data API (v3) Hosting In IIS

Tags: youtube-api

I used Youtube Data Api(v3) to get data from a Youtube Account.
I used this link https://console.developers.google.com/ to create ClientId and ClientSecret for a web application.

Everything works fine when I run my project in local. When I tried to host the project in server it gives a exception which says

> Access to the path ASP.****.aspx page is denied

When I debugged the solution, I noticed that this part of code causes the exception:

```
UserCredential credential;
credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync (
    new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId =  ClientId,
        ClientSecret =  ClientSecret

    },
    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly },
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore(GetType().ToString())
);
```

Comment: FileDatastore stores the files in %appdata% make sure it has access to that.   make sure you change the redirect uri in the Google developer console to the server as opposed to your localhost machine.   check firewall make sure your not blocking googles server for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for your reply DalmTo.. I did the things as you mentioned above.. But this time.. Page keeps on loading.. It's not even returning any exception nor output..

Answer (score 0):

Some methods inside google youtube api require OAUTH2 authentication (get refresh token from client secret ->get access token from refresh token...),upload videos for example, but some like getvideos do not require. You can provided API key to your youtubeService conctructor instead of UserCredential